# Searching and deletion in O(log n) time using arrays

Tags: data-structures, amortized-analysis

Suppose we are given a set of n numbers initially. We need to construct a data structure that supports Search(), Predecessor() and Deletion() queries.

Search and Predecessor should take worst case O(log processing n) time. Deletion should take amortized O(log n) time. Pre-time allowed is O(n). We initially have O(n) space. But I want that at any stage, if their are m numbers in the structure, the space used should be O(m)

This problem can be solved trivially using RBT, but I want a data structure that makes use of array(s) only. I don't want an implementation of RBT using arrays, the data structure shouldn't use any algorithms inspired from trees. Can anyone think of one such data structure?

Comment: The question is a little bit ambiguous; as explained i.e. [here](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/tree-as-array.html), a tree can also be implmeneted using an array. It is a bit unclear how the 'array but no tree' requirement is to be understood.

Comment: Okay. I am editting it a bit. Basically, I don't want to use any ideas inspired from trees at all.

Comment: are the numbers unique? i.e a set? would a  sorted list be useful for this?

Comment: Searching will take a lot of time in a list

Comment: And what about deletion? How is that to be done efficiently? @RyanVincent

Comment: mark them as deleted? you could mark each entry with a flag? or use a 'sentinal value'  such as -ve integer to mark them as deleted. The search will fail. The cost is similar to a search.

Comment: sorted arrays can get very expensive if they are very dynamic. However, that is true of arrays in memory anyway.

Comment: Looks good. Except for space. We initially take up O(n) space. But I want that at any stage, if their are m numbers in the structure, the space used should be O(m) @RyanVincent

Comment: I have reached the limit of my expertise on this subject. Was fun. Please post an answer, later, on what you finally did. It looks to be fun. I am interested.

Comment: @John, Red-black trees cannot be built in O(n) time unless the data is initially sorted somehow -- a property you did not specify. Additionally, when you say "number" what do you mean? 32-bit floating point? 64-bit unsigned integer? Arbitrary sized integers?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest some kind of tree structure, which is easy than RBT. To simplify it description, let number of elements in it will be `2^k`.

First level just numbers. 
Second a level a has `2^(k-1)` numbers, like in binary tree. 
Next level a has `2^(k-2)` numbers and so on until we have only one number. 
So we have a binary tree with `2^(k+1)` nodes, and parent will contain a maximum of it children values. To build this tree we will be `O(N)` time. Tree will consumer `O(n)` space, first level consumer `n`, second `n/2`, third `n/4` ... and so on, so total space will be `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... = 2n = O(n)`. E.g. we will have following tree for numbers 1,2,4,6,8,9,12,14:

```
 1  2  4  7  8  9 12  14 

   2    7     9     14 

      7          14

            14
```

To delete element we need find it using binary search and mark them null in list. Update tree, if both children NULL put NULL to the node. It will take k operation (the tree height) or O(log(N)). 
E.g. we delete 12.

```
 1  2  4  7  8  9 NULL(12)  14 

   2    7     9     14 

      7          14

            14
```

Now delete 7.

```
 1  2  4  NUll(7)  8  9 NULL(12)  14 

   2    4            9     14 

      4                 14

            14
```

Now we should search or predecessor in O(log(N)). By binary search find in first level our element or it predecessor. If it is not NULL we get the answer. If NULL go level up, we have three variants here:

1. Node has NULL value, go to upper level
2. Node's left child has a not NULL value. It is smaller then requested number (due tree structure) and it is the answer.
3. Node's value is bigger the then requested number, go upper.

Comment: Looks good. Except for space. We initially take up O(n) space. But I want that at any stage, if their are m numbers in the structure, the space used should be O(m)

Comment: In solution  O(n) space is used, first level takes n, second n/2, third n/4. So space consumed will be n+n/2+n/4 + ... + = 2n = O(n)

Comment: @John, Have a look at the definitions for Big-O notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation -- I think you'll realize what he suggested is already O(m). You seem to be implying you want to use as little space as possible -- Big-O notation will not help you state that as it's designed for broadly classifying algorithms and structures instead of specifying exact characteristics.

Comment: I see the problem, you can rebuilt tree if it will contains a less then n/2 elements. Is it will work for your?

Comment: @AlexanderKuznetsov Yeah, that seems like a better idea